# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, syntax-error, reserved-words

Is anyone able to tell me what is wrong with my code? The error I keep seeing is, *Missing ; before statement. (line 3, file "Code")*. I'm following a tutorial on YouTube and I can't tell what is the difference between my code and the tutors.

```
function createPDf () {    
  let studentname = "Example Smith";   
  let class = "S2H";    
  let year = "Year 4";    
  let Literacy = "Working at Stage outcomes";    
  let Numeracy: = "Working at Stage outcomes";    
  let socialinteractionsclassroom = "Usually";    
  let socialinteractionsplayground = "Usually";    
  let absences = "10";    
  let contactteacher = "yes";    
  let teacehername = "Mr Jacob Example";    
  let effort = "Usually";    

  // doc id 1c-DF4cCNu8Ma5khhL6FiMudmlc7E9XGrigpWPd-06lE    
  // temp folder 14I2Jql8BRaK3tPh0XNa8C9IoNkYuPRir    

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1c-DF4cCNu8Ma5khhL6FiMudmlc7E9XGrigpWPd-06lE");    
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("14I2Jql8BRaK3tPh0XNa8C9IoNkYuPRir");    
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);    
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());    
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();    
  body.replaceText("{Student name:}", studentname);    
  body.replaceText("{Class:}", class);    
  body.replaceText("{Year}", year);    
  body.replaceText("{Teacher Name}", teacehername);    
  body.replaceText("{Literacy}", Literacy);    
  body.replaceText("{Numeracy}", Numeracy);    
  body.replaceText("{Social interactions in the classroom}", socialinteractionsclassroom);    
  body.replaceText("{Social interactions in the playground}", socialinteractionsplayground);    
  body.replaceText("{Effort}", effort);    
  body.replaceText("{Absences exlcuding COVID}", absences);    
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();    

}
```

Comment: Which is line 3?

Comment: let studentname = "Example Smith";

Comment: Are you sure this is the Code.gs page?

Comment: I don't think that you can use the word class as a variable name because it's a key word in ES6

Comment: @Jacob - please, read the ECMAScript spec on [reserved keywords and words](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words), Cooper is absolutely right, this is what causes the error.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

Trying to name variable `class` results in a "Missing ; before statement" error.

**Explanation**

In [ECMAScript 262 spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words), there is a list of keywords and reserved words. You **cannot** use them in any other context that is defined for them (and some are even reserved for the future).

**List of reserved words ATTOW**

await | break | case | catch | class | const | continue | debugger | default | delete | do | else | export | extends | false | finally | for | function | if | import | in | instanceof | new | null | return | super | switch | this | throw | true | try | typeof | var | void | while | with | yield

**Reserved for the future**

enum | implements | interface | package | private | protected | public

**On error message**

You see the not-so-helpful error message because your script runs under the old [Rhino runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) GAS used. If you'd used the new one, V8 (please do [migrate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) as soon as possible), this is what you would've received:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class'

---

Actually, there is a second problem that will result in an error - using colon with [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) is not a valid JS syntax, but all credit should go to the other answer for noticing:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Answer (score 3):

Below are the lines I think they could be the reason:

```
let class = "S2H"; // class is a reserved words, so it cannot be used as a variable
let Numeracy: = "Working at Stage outcomes"; // the colon goes after Numeracy is wrong naming variable rule. You should remove or change it
```

ps: My English is not good so I hope you can get my idea. :)

Comment: PhucDinh - please, consider splitting the explanation from the code to make it more visible - it is correct, but I, for example, nearly missed it

Comment: @OlegValter I will do in the next question. Thanks a lot for reminding me :)